# Asp.Net MVC Entity Pass values from database by id and assign as variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What im trying to do here is to get value from my database by its id and have that value set so i can use to make calculation with. So i have id set as 1 and i have money and i want to do something like SELECT Balance FROM My_Table WHERE Id = 1; Is there a way to do this just by using the entity framework?

What i have done so far is.

In my DbEntity Model class.

```
public partial class CurrentAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }               
}
```

In my controller.

```
public class YourAccountsController : Controller
{
    // GET: YourAccount
    public ActionResult CurrentAccount(CurrentAccount ca)
    {
        return View(ca.Balance);
    }
}
```

Not worrying to much about the view atm as i can see when Balance has been assigned a db value in my locals and atm balance is set as 0.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if use Entity Framework is better.

Your Action

```
public ActionResult CurrentAccount(int Id)
{
  var model = context.CurrentAccounts.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == id);

    return view(model);
}
```

and pass id parameter with route for example :  `localhost:5277/YourAccounts/CurrentAccount/1`

Answer (score 1):

That is a GET action, so ideally you should be passing some information to this method (Ex : a unique id) and have some code which uses this unique id to get data from a data storage (your db table or a web service) etc. Since y  ou are using EF, you can use that to get data.

```
public ActionResult CurrentAccount(int Id)
{
   var item= myDbContext.CurrentAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id);
   if(item!=null)
   {
     return View(item.Balance);
   }
   return Content("Account not found"); // To do: May be return a view      
}
```

Assuming `myDbContext` is the object of your db context class and `CurrentAccounts` is the DbSet collection (`DbSet<CurrentAccount>`) property in that and your CurrentAccount view is strongly typed to a decimal type.

Now you access the url with the account id. Ex : `yourSite/yourController/CurrentAccount/1`

Comment: This approach looks great however im not to understanding of using a DbContext atm so to pull it in from a model was easier for me. Ill have to do a little more reading on this approach. Thank you Shyju :)